# How to Get the Base Url of a Server-Side Blazor App

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a server-side blazor app and I need to know it's base url (e.g. `https://localhost:1234` or `https://my-host.com/appname`).

In a traditional ASP.NET web application, I could inspect the `Request` property of a controller and retrieve the information from it (there's `Scheme`, `Host`, and `PathBase` for that). But since this is a *server-side* running Blazor app, there is no `Request` object (at least in my understanding and except maybe when serving the `Index.cshtml`).

How can I then know, to which URL my app has been deployed to and is running at?

Ideally, I would already have this information at startup time, so that I can configure my services accordingly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Getting it inside a page is easy:

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigator

<p>@Navigator.BaseUri</p>
```

But you can't use a `NavigationManager` in the `Startup` class.

Comment: That already helps a lot. I can build a work-around with this until somebody figures out how to get this at startup.

Comment: If there is a NuGet pkg required for this it would be nice if this information is *always* included with answers. It cannot be assumed that we would know.

Comment: I thumbed this up even in Oct 2020 because it lead me to the right direction but for those coming here now for .NET 5 have a look at the NavigationManager.

Comment: So, is it safe to say that there is no practical way to get the base URL in the `Program.cs`  file where there is `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` in a Blazor Server-side project?  ---- Because, I saw a sample project of Blazor WebAssembly project, where the author used `var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args); builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress` in the `Program.cs` of the Client project.

Comment: @DamnVegetables - this is an old answer but mostly **it is for Blazor-Server**. No HostEnvironhment there.

Answer (score 12):

In .Net Core 3.0 onwards `IUriHelper` has been replaced by `NavigationManager`

To use inside a Blazor page:

```
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

   //example usage
   var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(NavigationManager.BaseUri);
```